# What is the best data structure to model a path through an undirected graph?

Tags: ocaml, graph-theory, modeling, 2d-games

I'm working on modeling a path search and deduction board game, to practice some concepts I am learning in school. This is a first attempt at analyzing graphs for me, and I would appreciate some advice on what kind of data structure might be appropriate for what I am trying to do.

The game I am modeling presents as a series of ~200 interconnected nodes, as shown below. Given a known starting position for the adversary (node 84, for example, in the figure below) the goal is to identify possible locations of the adversary's hideout. The adversary's moves away from 84 are, naturally unknown.

[Fig 1 - Illustrative Sub-Graph with Adversary Initial Position at Node 84](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QMow.png)

Initially, this leads to a situation like the one below. Given the adversary started at 84, he/she can only be at 66, 86 or 99 after taking their first turn. And so on.

[Fig 2 - Possible Locations for Adversary after 1, 2 and 3 Turns (Based on Fig 1 Graph)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unLZQ.png)

So far, I have modeled the board itself as an undirected graph - using an implementation of OCaml's ocamlgraph library. What I am now trying to do is to model the path taken by the adversary through the graph, so as to identify potential locations of the adversary after each turn.

While convenient for illustration purposes, the tree representation implied by the figure above has several drawbacks:

First, keeping track of all possible paths through the network is unnecessary (I care only about terminal location of the adversary's hideout, not the path taken) as well as burdensome: each node is connected to ~7 other nodes, on average. By the time we hit the end of the game's 15 turns, that's a lot of branches!

Second, I suspect pruning would become an issue as well. Indeed, part of the exercise here is to maximally exploit the limited information about the adversary's movements that revealed as the game goes on. This information either states that the adversary "has never been to node X" or "has previously visited node X."

Information of the first type (e.g. "adversary has never been to node 65") would lead me to want to prune the tree "from above" by traveling down through the branches and cutting off any branch that is invalidated by the revealed information.

[Fig 3 - Pruning from the Top ("Adversary Has Never Been to Node 65")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oakrv.png)

Information of the second type (e.g. "Adversary has Visited Node 100") would, however, invite pruning "from below" to cut off any branch that was not consistent with the information.

[Fig 4 - Pruning from the Bottom (e.g. "Adversary Has Visited Node 100")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSkc6.png)

It seems to me that a naive tree approach would be a messy proposition, so I thought I would ask for any suggestions or advice on the best data structure to use here, or how to better approach the problem.

Comment: The two pruning strategies you are describing do not seem to care about order. Therefore, you could represent different paths with sets rather than trees. You will have a lot of sets instead of having a lot of branches but the pruning actions will be somewhat quicker. It is worth noting that you gain a little by reducing duplication.

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to give advice for your case, as any optimization should be preceded by profiling. It sounds like you need a bitset of some sort and/or incidence matrix. For BitSet you can either use [Batteries implementation](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org/doc.preview:batteries-alpha3/html/api/BitSet.html) or just implement your own using OCaml arbitrary precision numbers with [Zarith library](https://github.com/ocaml/Zarith). For incidence matrix, you can opt into trivial `_ array array`, use the Bigarray module, or, again, use Zarith and implement your own efficient representation using bitwise operations.

And if I were you, I would start with defining the abstraction that you need (i.e., the interface) then start with a drop in implementation, and later optimize based on the real input, by substituting implementations.